# Git config edit color with multiple styles

Tags: git, grep, output, git-config, git-grep

does any of you know if there a way to apply git color with both bold and underline (or as a more general question - apply color with multiple style args)?

I try to set git config color.grep.filename to be green, bold and underline...
It seems as if I can't do it and must choose between bold and underline.

I tried the obvious way and got an error

```
git config color.grep.filename green bold ul
```

then I tried this way and only ul passed through

```
git config color.grep.filename green bold
git config color.grep.filename ul
```

then I tried hardcoded like this and only one of them worked

```
git config --add color.grep.filename "green ul bold"
```

and lastly I tried this way and got only bold green to work

```
git config --add color.grep.filename ul
git config --add color.grep.filename green bold
```

Is there something I am missing or is it just not a possibility to combine?

Thanks for the help :D

Comment: Git implements colorized text and other effects (bold, inverse, underline) through escape sequences: ESC, `[`, digits, `m` (this is actually an ANSI standard!). It's up to your terminal emulator to turn these into actual displayed colors and effects. Your terminal emulation *may* (emphasis on may) have ways to make this work better, but this obviously depends on which terminal emulator you use.

Comment: A lot of Mac users swear by iterm (in its various incarnations). I still just use plain old Terminal though.

Comment: @torek I use ubuntu 18.04 native terminal (I believe its GNOME terminal)

Answer (score 0):

Reading [`git config` colors](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-color), I just tried:

```
git -c color.grep.filename="yellow ul bold" grep seec
```

It does work for yellow. Meaning I see a difference between "`yellow ul`" and "`yellow ul bold`".
But not  for green or blue, in my Git for Windows session (CMD).
It might depend on your actual shell though.

- `yellow ul`
  [image: yellow ul]
- `yellow ul bold` or `yellow bold ul`
  [image: yellow ul bold]

Comment: I tried that for my combination only and it didn't work (meaning I tried with green and not yellow). Anyways, im using ubuntu's shell so we might have a difference

Comment: @Hacktivator Ubuntu shell in a WSL2 session on Windows? Or directly on Ubuntu host? Which version is your OS and Git?

Comment: @Hacktivator I have edited the answer to include pictures illustrating what I see with those attributes.

Comment: I use ubuntu 18.04 directly as host, no windows OS involved, and git v 2.17.1 @VonC

Comment: @Hacktivator Can you try and upgrade to latest 2.30.1?